# Identify orientation with degrees on startup

Tags: react-native

Without a 3rd party lib, we can detect orientation changes with DeviceEventEmitter with this undocumented feature like this:

```
import { DeviceEventEmitter } from 'react-native'

function handleOrientationDidChange(data) {
    console.log('orientation changed, data:', data)
}

DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('namedOrientationDidChange', handleOrientationDidChange);
```

This gives us data that looks like this:

```
{ rotationDegrees: -90, isLandscape: true, name: "landscape-primary" }
```

> Note: I tested this only on Android. It would be nice to know if it works on iOS too.

However this only works **ON CHANGE**. Is there a way to get this info on startup?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [this library](https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation)!

Here is example usage from the repo:

```
componentWillMount() {
    // The getOrientation method is async. It happens sometimes that
    // you need the orientation at the moment the JS runtime starts running on device.
    // `getInitialOrientation` returns directly because its a constant set at the
    // beginning of the JS runtime.

    const initial = Orientation.getInitialOrientation();
    if (initial === 'PORTRAIT') {
      // do something
    } else {
      // do something else
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Omar, I actually should have mentioned I'm trying to do this without installing another lib. I feel I'm close it should be somewhere in here, because they offer this info out of the box on change.

Comment: @Noitidart Have you figured it out how to detect the initial device orientation without 3rd party libraries?

Comment: @dmitryame - I have not :(  i didn't actively work on it though.